# Equal distance grouped bar chart irrespective of scale - chart.js

Tags: angular, charts, chart.js, bar-chart, grouped-bar-chart

I have a requirement that need to show up data in bar graph using chart.js like below,
[image]

Here, irrespective of x-axis date, the bars should be aligned in equal distance and the date format is same as in the image.

```
let chartStatus = Chart.getChart(this.WEIGHTS_CHART);
if (chartStatus != undefined) {
  chartStatus!.destroy();
}

const weightsChart = new Chart(this.WEIGHTS_CHART, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: this.objWeights.map(x => x.date),
    datasets: [
      {
        label: "Weight",
        backgroundColor: "#0072bc",
        data: this.objWeights.map(x => x.weightValue)
      },
      {
        label: "BMI",
        backgroundColor: "#84b5e4",
        data: this.objWeights.map(x => x.bmi)
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
      x: {
        type: 'time',
        time: {
          unit: 'day',
          displayFormats: {
            day: 'MMM DD, YYYY'
          }
        }
      },
      y: {
        beginAtZero: true
      }
    }
  }
});
}
```

with the above code, I'm getting output like this [image]. Can someone help me

I want like this
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Aiwj.png)

but with above code, I'm getting like this
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkMGO.png)

Answer (score 0):

Make your x-axis of `type: 'timeseries'` instead of `type: 'time'`.

> [**Time Series Axis**](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/timeseries.html): The time series scale extends from the time scale and supports all the same options. However, for the time series scale, each data point is spread equidistant.

```
scales: {
  x: {
    type: 'timeseries',
    time: {
      ...
```